# Постоянная переменная: как мне между моими страничками передавать название вендора во Flask

Tags: python, веб-программирование, сессия, flask

Добрый день, появился очень щепетильный вопрос . У меня есть база диалогов У которой есть вендор (Владелец самой базы или же от куда она у нас появилась)
Вопрос в чем как мне между моими страничками передавать название вендора , первое что пришло в голову это

```
<input name="vendor" value="{{ vendor }}" hidden>
```

Считывать его при каждом запросе

```
request.args.get('vendor')
```

и передевать дальше по цепечке при рендере шаблона как скрытое поле что может занять много кода .
второе предложение это использовать куки . в самом app.route("/")
написать функцию

```
cookie=request.cookies.get('vendor')
retrun resp.set_cookie('vendor', 'vendor.cookie.ru') 
if cookie is not None 
  retrun resp.set_cookie('vendor', 'vendor.cookie.ru')
else:
  return redirect("set_cookie")
```

Или же запихивать его в шлобальную переменую , может прикрутить логин к системе и в сесию складывать 
Вопрос что быстрей и потом меньшу будет составлять проблем.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Using session in flask app](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18139910/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После небольшого раздумівания решил приьегнуть к методу с куки , на много проще 
в кажлом обработчие поместил

```
vendor=get_vendor()
    if vendor is None: return redirect('set_cookie')
```

и еще есть вот такие 2 штуки

```
@app.route("/set_cookie", methods=['GET'])
def set_cookie():
    vendor=request.args.get('vendor')
    if vendor is None : return redirect('chose_vendor')
    redirect_to_index = redirect('/')
    response = current_app.make_response(redirect_to_index)
    response.set_cookie('vendor', value='author24.ru')
    return response

def get_vendor():
    cookie = request.cookies.get('vendor')
    if cookie is not None:
        return cookie
    else:
        return None
```

я подозреваю что меня могут захаять за то что я вінес бизнесовую переменную в куки , по доброму надо било би ее в сессию вписівать  п прикрутить ее к g.user но єто метот работи Agile поєтому на отладку все потом.